# lan transfer speeds

Tags: performance, lan

I have been trying to figure out what is limiting my lan transfer speeds.  I have openwrt/lede on my linksys router, and a samba server running on it with a usb hdd plugged in.

My last device, a M8s Pro was transferring at kilobytes a second across the lan ([see post here for more details](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android-stick--console-computers/amlogic/bad-wifi-strength-m8s-pro-t3698391))

I also have a Nvidia Shield tablet and a newly purchased Leelbox Q3 box.  On these the lan transfer speed is about 3.5 to 4.5 mb/s

Which is alot better but my laptop gets around 20 to 40 mb/s

What is the problem here, why cant I reach speeds similar to my laptop on these android devices?
Is it hard drive write speeds or the wifi chips in them?

I ask because I want to return this leelbox and get something that is going to be comparable to my laptop.

Comment: How do you connect the phone to the LAN? Are you using an USB to Ethernet adapter?

Comment: its an android tv box, it has an ethernet port built into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not 100% this is my final answer however after further searching I found that there is no SMBv3 support till Oreo and some suggested to try FTP.

So I installed FTP on my openwrt and tried that for transferring files.  Now instead of 3.5 to 4.5 mb/s, Im getting 7mb/s which is almost double and better then before but still not the speeds I see on my laptops (using 5ghz wifi).